# Texture map to control pixel colors in a THREE.Points mesh

Tags: three.js

I'm fairly new to Three.js, but I'm trying to use a Texture map to control pixel colors in a THREE.Points mesh.  My desired outcome is that vertex 0 will be colored as image pixel x=0, y=0.  Vertex 1 will be colored as image x=1, y=0, and so on.

All attempts I have make result is each vertex point being rendered with the whole image (not use one color according to the coordinates.)

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
... Define Geometry ...
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/MyImage.jpg");
var mat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size: 2.5, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, map: texture });
var points = new THREE.Points(geo, mat);
```

Comment: For one way, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659461/rendering-a-large-number-of-colored-particles-using-three-js-and-the-canvas-rend/12663852#12663852.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like you have to use a texure (maybe that is possible with a similar approach) you could just read the pixeldata of the image and use that to set colors similar to WestLangleys suggestion.

I'm not sure if the difference between colors size and number of vertices are going to be a problem, but it's working fine for me. Good luck!

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "Image1.png";

img.onload = function(){

    // apply image to canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);

    var colors = [];

    // geometry of choice
    var geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50,50);

    for(var i = 0; i < img.width; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < img.height; j++){

            // pd - pixeldata array in the format of rgba. example: [53, 53, 130, 255]
            var pd = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(i,j,1,1).data;

            // not pretty, but works
            colors.push(new THREE.Color("rgb("+pd[0]+","+pd[1]+","+pd[2]+")"));
        }
    }
    geo.colors = colors;

    var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {size: 10, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });

    var point = new THREE.Points(geo, material);
    scene.add(point);
};
```

Comment: `THREE.Color` does not have an alpha component.

Comment: @WestLangley Good catch. Fixed

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, your approach is actually what I'm already doing (hence why I have vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors in my PointsMaterial.)  It works very well, but I was looking for a way to avoid management of image pixel color to vertex color array.  I figured a texture map would handle that for me.  I also thought it might give a performance boost (but this is just a guess.)