# How to set vertex colors of THREE.Points object in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to write a function that creates a point cloud from mesh. I also want to control colors of every vertex of that point cloud. So far I tried to assign colors of geometry but colors doesnt being updated.

```
InteractablePointCloud_simug=function(object, editor){

        var signals=editor.signals;

        var vertexSize=0.3;
        var pointMat= new THREE.PointsMaterial({size:vertexSize , vertexColors:THREE.VertexColors});

        var colors=[];
        var colorStep=0.1;

         for (var i = 0; i < object.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
            colors.push(new 
            THREE.Color(colorStep*i,colorStep*i,colorStep*i));

         };

        //get points from mesh of original object
        var points=new THREE.Points(object.geometry,pointMat);

        //Update colors
        points.geometry.colors=colors;
        points.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate=true;


        updatePosition();

        //Add points object to scene
        editor.addNoneObjectMesh(points);
   }
```

Comment: Try `new THREE.Color( r, g, b )`, where r, g, b are in the range [ 0, 1 ]. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12663852/1461008.

Comment: I am already using new THREE.Color()

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably doable on other video cards, but mine does not seem to like it.

Theoretically.. if your material color is white.. it should multiply times the vertex color ( which is basically like using the vertex color ), but since you did not specify black as your color, this is not the problem ).

If your code is not working on your computer ( not on mine either ), you will have to go nuclear... and just create a new `selectedPointsGeometry` and a new `selectedPointsMesh`

Grab a couple of vertices from the original.. copy them.. put them in a `vertices` array.. and run an update method ( you have to recreate the geo and mesh every time.. at least on my PC, I tried calling every single update method, and had to resort to recreating )

mind the coffee script.  `@anchor` is the container

```
  updateSelectedVertices: (vertices) ->
    if @selectedParticles
      @anchor.remove @selectedParticles

    @pointGeometry = new THREE.Geometry()

    @pointGeometry.vertices = vertices

    @selectedParticles = new (THREE.PointCloud)(
      @pointGeometry,
      @selectedPointMaterial
    )
    @pointGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
    @pointGeometry.computeLineDistances()
    @selectedParticles.scale.copy @particles.scale
    @selectedParticles.sortParticles = true
    @anchor.add @selectedParticles
```

`selectedPointMaterial` is defined elsewhere.  Just use a different color ( and different size ).. than your non selected point cloud.

IE.. use black and size 5 for non selected point cloud , and use yellow and 10 for the selected one.

My other mesh is called `@particles`.. and I just have to copy the scale. (this is the non-selected point cloud)

Now my selected points show as yellow
[image]